# How to addClass if the div has 2 others class

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'd like to add new class to my div if this div has 2 others classes, that I've set first by clicking on the div and second randomly

```
    function selection() { 
        $(".ok").click(function () {
            if ($(".green").length < 7) {
                $(this).addClass("green");
            }
        });

    }
    function bluecolor() { 
        $(".boutton2").click(function () {
                for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                    var rn = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + 1;
                    $("#" + rn).addClass("blue");
                }
                if("div" .green .blue == true){
                    $("div" .green .blue).addClass("orange");
                }
            });
        }
```

The problem is that my divs green and bue are blue and not orange, I think i have an if condition problem but i can't solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make use of `hasClass()` method to check your div already having class or not if not having add it

```
if("div" .green .blue == true){
```

change it to

```
$("div.green.blue").length >0
```

Answer (score 0):

I think no need to use `if` statement you can directly use

```
$("div.green.blue").addClass("orange");
```

In Code

```
function bluecolor() { 
     $(".boutton2").click(function () {
        for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            var rn = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + 1;
            $("#" + rn).addClass("blue");
        }
        $("div.green.blue").addClass("orange");
    });
 }
```

Example:

```js
$('div.green.blue').addClass('orange');
```

```css
.green{
  background : green;
}
.blue{
  background : blue;
}
.orange{
  background : orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="blue">1</div>
<div class="blue">2</div>
<div class="blue">3</div>
<div class="blue green">4</div>
<div class="blue">5</div>
<div class="blue green">6</div>
```